# `animation-fill-mode: none;` not working

Tags: css, css-animations

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode, the `animation-fill-mode: none;` should not apply style of the first frame to the element before the animation starts. However, `animation-fill-mode: backwards` should.

But in this [demo](http://codepen.io/daiweilu/pen/wphDH) of the below code, it seems like `none` is doing the job `backwards` should. Why?

```
/* I have autoprefixer enabled */
div {
  width: 100px; 
  height: 100px; 
  background-color: red;
  transform: translate(0, 0);
  animation: someAnimation 1s linear 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: none;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: none;
}

@keyframes someAnimation {
  0% {
    transform: translate(50px, 50px);
  }

  100% {
    transform: translate(100px, 100px);
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you end up solving your issue?

Comment: @ZachSaucier no, your demo uses `backwards`, but my question is "why `none` acts the same as `backwards`?"

Comment: My answer was that they are different, your setup was just wrong :P

Comment: @ZachSaucier I don't quite understand, did you mean in your example, `none` act differently from `backwards`?

Comment: Yes, one jumps at the start while the other doesn't

Comment: @ZachSaucier you sample worked, I will mark it right. Somehow in Chrome, if I set `none` and `1s` delay, it just act like `backwards`. If increase the delay, I will briefly see the delay. Other browser worked just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You misspelled `animation-fill-mode` in the first statement
2. You don't have a `-webkit-` prefix for the animation and transition properties nor do you enable prefix free, so webkit is not being served

Once you [fix those](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/hNp76/) they work differently as they should

Comment: I corrected the misspell, `animation-fill-mode: none` still won't work. Whatever I do, `none` worked exactly the same as `backwards` which is not what I wanted. (I have autoprefixer enabled.)

Comment: @Daiwei What browser are you using?

Comment: Latest Chrome, I haven't test this in Firefox

Comment: @Daiwei The two have different effects for me in the latest Chrome. The only difference is where the element is at the start of the animation